# Algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose an oracle knows a natural number nthat you wish to know.

The oracle answers only Yes/No, to the following three types of queries:

1. Is the number greater than x ?
2. Is the number lesser than x ?
3. Is the number equal to x ?

(where x can be an arbitrary natural number, that can changed across queries).

Describe a method for posing queries to the oracle, which is asymptotically efficient in the number of queries posed.

Perform the analysis and write a proof of correctness. Note that the number of queries posed will be a function of n

Comment: Please tell us what you know so that we can build on that.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not very fair as it requires asymptotic efficiency, without giving any hint on the goal. We can use an informal information theoretic bound and say that the answer conveys `i` bits of information, which is `Omega(i)=Omega(Lg n)`.

### The algorithm

Phase 1: find the number of significant bits.

```
Ask x<1b, x<10b, x<100b, x<1000b, x<10000b, x<100000b... (all powers of 2)
until you get a yes.
```

Phase 2: find all bits.

```
Take the value of the last bound where phase 1 stopped and divide it by 2.
Then, going from the second most significant to the least significant bit, 
set the next bit and ask if <x. Keep the bit set if you get a no.
```

### Example

Let us assume `x=10110b`, your questions will go as follows:

```
x<1b ? no
x<10b ? no
x<100b ? no
x<1000b ? no
x<10000b ? no
x<100000b ? yes

Q=10000b
x<11000b ? yes
Q=10000b
x<10100b ? no
Q=10100b
x<10110b ? no
Q=10110b
x<10111b ? yes
Q=10110b
```

For 5 bits, 10 questions.

### Correctness

In phase 1, the search intervals form a partition of the integers and the search will stop sooner or later. When it stops, `P<=x<2P` holds, where P is a power of 2,or `2^k<=x<2^(k+1)`.

In phase 2, we keep the invariant condition `Q<=x<Q+2^(k+1)` by iterative halving (initially `Q=0`): given `Q<=x<Q+2^(k+1)`, we ask for `x<Q+2^k` and conclude either `Q<=x<Q+2^k` or `Q+2^k<=x<Q+2^(k+1)`, which we turn to `Q'<=x<Q'+2^k` by setting `Q'=Q+2^k`. In the end, `Q<=x<Q+1`.

### Efficiency

Phase 1 takes as many queries as there are significant bits.

Phase 2 takes as many queries as there are significant bits.

Comment: Quick note: The usage of `n` as the number of bits is misleading, since the question explicitly says: `Suppose an oracle knows a natural number n `, and later asks `the number of queries posed will be a function of n`,  so the number `n` in the complexity function should be the number itself (making the complexity of the problem `Omega(logn)` and of the algorithm `Theta(logn)` - or define a new variable `k=lg(n)` that will be used for the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Wikipedia post on binary search algorithm. That can be a starting point for you.

[Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm%23Number_guessing_game)

Comment: This is not enough, as you have no upper bound.

Comment: She can do a one-sided binary search. Still possible to use the algorithm.